# Comparison of NEAR and Celestia Data Aavailability Approaches?

Tags: scalability, rollups, architecture, data, near

Recently NEAR has come up with a Data Availiabity approach which they claim to be far more superior to a lot of existing techniques. Celestia DA leverages 2D Erasure Coding based Data Availability sampling whereas NEAR DA leverages their unique approach using Sharding techniques. NEAR DA leverages its own consensus algorithm and uses contract blob stores. Celestia DA approach uses Namespace based Merkle Trees as its own custom data structure. What are the comparative advantages of NEAR DA compared to Celestia DA?

Comment: Unfortunately this technologies are unrelated to Ethereum. It will be better to ask about them in their respective forums.

Answer (score 1):

Great questions, let me break this down for you Gokul.

> Both NEAR DA and Celestia DA approaches are based on data availability sampling techniques.

Celestia is a blockchain that relies on DAS, whereas NEAR currently doesn't have DAS, but has the primitives to build if needed. It's however correct that, we leverage Nightshade to build our DA layer, coupled with a smart contract that optimises cost for the rollup operator.

If you are looking to learn more about what is NEAR DA and why NEAR doesn't use DAS (yet), take a look at [this recent blog post](https://near.org/blog/why-near-data-availability).

I will take an excerpt from the latest post to show some of the differences between NEAR DA and Celestia:

> Instead of relying on data availability sampling (DAS), a rollup can
> rely on its own shard by running a lightweight RPC through Data
> Availability with Sharding. The additional benefit here is that the
> RPC is also applying the chunks they are tracking, essentially acting
> as a validator without participating in the consensus, as opposed to
> statistical confidence with DAS.